# How to comment out rails 3.1 asset require statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

Is it possible to comment out this line in the new app/assets/application.js file?  If so, how?

```
//=require jquery_ujs
```

I mean, it's already commented out to avoid being misconstrued as CoffeeScript or JavaScript, but it's obviously serving a purpose still.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Taken from the [Sprockets 1.02 github](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/tree/1.0.2) (Sprockets 2 is what rails 3.1 uses to accomplish asset loading):

> How Sprockets handles comments
>
> Use single-line (//) comments in
>   JavaScript source files for comments
>   that don't need to appear in the
>   resulting concatenated output.Use
>   multiple-line (/* ... */) comments for
>   comments that should appear in the
>   resulting concatenated output, like
>   copyright notices or descriptive
>   headers. PDoc (/** ... **/)
>   documentation comments will not be
>   included in the resulting
>   concatenation.
>
> Comments beginning with //= are
>   treated by Sprockets as directives.
>   Sprockets currently understands two
>   directives, require and provide.

What this means is that `//= jquery_ujs` is a directive. It instructs Sprockets to include the jquery_uls file when it compiles all the jquery files.

**If you don't want that file included, just remove the equals sign and the directive becomes a comment.**

Answer (score 13):

Short and fast ...

```
//require jquery_ujs
```

... just remove the = sign.

Answer (score 5):

What I hate about this, is that it is really looking for a `=` inside a single line comment instead of the combination of `//=`.

To disable, put the `//` after the `//=`:

```
//= // require jquery_ujs
```

or kill the equal sign

```
// require jquery_ujs
```

Anything before the `=` will not work:

```
//!= require jquery_ujs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
///* My Application Scripts
//= 'require jquery'
//= 'require jquery_ujs'
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
*///
```

require lines with ('') will not be loaded.